# how to dynamically replace images in a div

Tags: jquery

my problem sounds simple but I have not been able to figure it out.
I'm trying to add a new img into a div tag(#box) through links. The problem I'm running into is that the first link works and then I can't get the second link to replace the previous img in the div tag called (#box) I have provided this hope it helps:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonsanc76/cP5DX/1/)

```
<body>
<p id="link1"><a href="#">image1</a></p>
<p id="link2"><a href="#">image2</a></p><br />
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is instead of changing the contents of `#box`, you are trying to append the new elements to the already added `img` element

Since what you need is to replace the image in the `#box` element, you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

In this scenario, looks like you can use

```
$(function(){
    $("#link1").on("click",function(){
        $("#box").html('<a href="http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com"><img src="http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/dhltest.jpg" alt="dhl" target="_new" style="border:none;"/>');
    });


    $("#link2").on("click",function(){
        $("#box").html('<a href="http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com"><img src="http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/ibmtest.jpg" alt="ibm" target="_new" style="border:none;"/>');
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3pdMs/)

Comment: I'm going to try this. I will get back to you

Comment: I was about to ask you about that, when you press one link more than once it would keep populating more elements. Thanks again! for this code also.

Comment: what does the substring(1) actually do so that I can understand what it's actually doing?

Comment: @cm8188 if you look at the `<a` tag I've changed the `href` attribute value, and it is prefixed with `#`. so when I generate the `src` of the image it has to be removed

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append to an `<img/>` element.

```
$("#box>img").append
```

to

```
$('#box').append
```

As a side note, that development account may have just been terminated for hotlink TOS'ing

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kufF/)

Comment: I must of hot-linked by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the attribute when click on the second image.

```
$("#link2").on("click",function(){
    $("#box img").attr('src','http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/ibmtest.jpg');
});
```

Comment: Yeah but I want the image to be a preview. ultimately it's supposed to add an image that is clickable to open into another window. So the first click is for the preview and if you click the image it's supposed to go to that image on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one..

HTML:

```
<p id="link1"><a href="#">image1</a></p>
<p id="link2"><a href="#">image2</a></p>

<br />
<div ><img src="http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/dhltest.jpg" id="box" >       </a></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#link1").on("click",function(){
    $('#box').attr("src", "http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/dhltest.jpg"); 
});


$("#link2").on("click",function(){

   $('#box').attr("src", "http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/test/images/ibmtest.jpg"); 
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with image with changeing div use:

html:

```
<div id="box"><img id="imgId" src=""></div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var url = "";    
    $("#link1").on("click",function(){
            var url = your.url;
            $('#imgId').attr("src", url);
    });


    $("#link2").on("click",function(){
        var url = your.url;
            $('#imgId').attr("src", url);
    });


});
```

and with this u can have as many pictures as u like changeing in same div

PS if u don't like your img beeing empty on load u can use

```
display:none;
```

css attribute

and then use `.show();` function when clicking first time
or set url to some default value

Comment: I can see the value of this when you have unlimited or an unknown number of images. Thanks.

Comment: Well if you are working for a client its always a good idea to consider that there will be aditional pics or info that he will ask of you to show, so (in my humble opinion) always try to make your code "unspecific" for your problem, and easy to "upgrade"

Comment: Point duly noted. I will keep this in mind for the future. I guess this is a perfect example of "scalable design".